# Cooking peanut butter cookies, is there any adjustment using crunchy vs. creamy?

Tags: baking, substitutions, cookies

I assume most recipes call for creamy.
Should I use more crunchy?
Should there be a cooking adjustment for time or temp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. For peanut butter cookies it's just a matter of taste, and it's 1:1.

Comment: Won't the cookies (the part that isn't peanut chunks) be more "floury" if it's substituted 1:1?

Comment: @Random832 In my experience, no. Even though recipes often specify creamy or chunky, I have always just used whatever I have on hand. I've made them hundreds of times, from different recipes, they're a go-to rainy day kind of thing. I have a batch in the works right now, as a matter of fact. I have never noticed any issue or problem with straight subbing back and forth.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely no difference.  The small volume that the nuts take up is not enough to change the consistency of the product.

Around here they sell extra-crunchy.